# Why is this event handler from a class loop not responding?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looping through 10 divs with the same class to add event handlers which should change the border on a mouse click. I'm using getElementsByClassName. There is no response to the click on any of the divs. The simple function worked on another div in an event handler.

The html:

```
<div class="note-small">
    <p>blah</p>
</div>
```

I used this vanilla JS:

```
const note_small_class = document.getElementsByClassName('note-small');

for (let i=0; i < note_small_class.length; i++) {
  note_small_class[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    highlightNote(note_small_class[i]);
  })
};

function highlightNote(note) {
  note.style.background.color = 'red';
};
```

note_small_class shows as an object (HTML collection) in the console. Something isn't working, I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have this javascript wrapped in a document ready callback?  it's possible this is running before the DOM is available.  You might need that to be wrapped in something like `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   // Your code goes here
});`

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem. Much appreciated,

Answer (score 2):

```
note.style.background.color = 'red';
```

There seems to be an issue with what you are setting the style to be, the property should be `backgroundColor`, not `background.color`, try this:

```
note.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

Comment: This was also a problem, thanks.